# fwrite prints unwanted NUL in linux

Tags: c

Various versions of this question have been asked but unfortunately none of them explains the behavior I see with fwrite.

I am trying to read a file(fread) into a buffer and then write the buffer(fwrite) into another file. The number of bytes written by fwrite is as expected but when I print out the file I see a 'NUL' character at the end which is not present in the original file.

Here are the relevant sections of the code,

```
fps = fopen(source, "rb");
fpd = fopen(destination, "w+b");

// Get source file size
fseek(fps,0L,SEEK_END);
filesize = ftell(fps)+1;
fseek(fps,0L,SEEK_SET); //Reset file pointer

char *buffer = malloc(filesize * sizeof *buffer);
fread(buffer,1,filesize,fps);
int dsize = fwrite(buffer,1,filesize,fpd);
```

And here is the code that prints the "destination" file by each character.

```
int c;
while ((c = fgetc(fpd)) != EOF) {
    printf("Character -> %d\n", c);
}
printf("Character EOF-> %d\n", c);
```

I believe this has something to do with the way 'buffer' is defined but I am truly at my wits end.

Thanks much for the help!

Comment: Notes: `fwrite` returns a type `size_t` which may exceed that range of `int`.  Better to use `size_t dsize = ...`.  Even the result from `ftell(fps)` may be insufficient as files  could be larger than processor address space.  `fgetpos()` uses type `fpos_t` to uniquely every position within a file.  Of course if a file is HUGE, it may be impossible to allocate enough memory for the need.

Answer (score 4):

This

```
fseek(fps,0L,SEEK_END);
```

does not place the current position *at* the last byte of the file. It places the current position *beyond* the last byte of of the file (immediately past the last byte). Which means that file size is

```
filesize = ftell(fps);
```

You should not add 1 to it. Your attempt to read that one extra byte (which does not exist in reality) is what produces that extra character in the destination file.

Comment: My understanding was that fseek(fps,0L,SEEK_END) sets the pointer to 'EOF'. So shouldn't EOF be included as part of the file?

Comment: @greywanderer: On a typical platform `EOF` is not part of the file. It is an exit code returned by IO functions when you attempt to read non-existent data past the end-of-file. Even if your platform physically stores the EOF marker in the file itself, you are not able to physically read it anyway using C standard library functions. In any case, it is not your responsibility to copy that character. EOF is implicitly handled by the platform.

Comment: @AnT Thanks for that clarification. But even if EOF is not supposed to be part of the file and is included(extra byte), shouldn't the source and destination be the same files at the end of the copy? Why are they different? The source file has a 'NewLine'(ASCII 10) character before '-1'(EOF?) while the destination has a 'NUL'(ASCII 0) character before '-1'.

Comment: @greywanderer: I don't see how they could be the same. Let's say the original file has size 100. You allocate a buffer of size 101 and ask `fread` to read 101 bytes. It reads only 100 (check the return value of `fread`). The 101th byte in the buffer contains garbage. Then you write 101 bytes into the destination (including the extra garbage byte). The destination ends up being 101 bytes long. End of story.

Comment: I don't understand your "newline" remark. If your source file had a newline before the end, the destination file will also have newline before the garbage character. No way around it.

Comment: You are right. The 'NUL' character happens to be the garbage character. And I do see the 'NL' before the 'NUL' character.

Comment: EOF is not data... EOF is the condition of reading on the end of file, that leads **write(2)** to return inmediately the number of characters read (in this case, 0 chars)